# Get token for OAuth2 in Laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, oauth, oauth-2.0

So, I need to get the authorization code that is being sent to my site by the host in an OAuth2 situation where I am the client. When the host sends back an authorization code, what is the proper way to strip the code from the URL and then send it back to retrieve a token and secret?

I have tried stripping the code in the htaccess and storing it as an environment variable using the code below, but that isn't storing the environment variable properly.

htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MY_AUTH:%1]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/cadWithAuth? [L]
```

Router

```
Route::get('/cadWithAuth', 'FileController@cadWithAuth')->name('files.cadWithAuth');
```

Controller

```
public function cadWithAuth( )
{
    $authCode = getenv('MY_AUTH');
    $authID = getenv('OAUTH_CLIENT_ID');
    $authSecret = getenv('OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET');
    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
    $result = $client->post('https://oauth.hostsite.com/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'code' => $authCode,
            'client id' => $authID,
            'client_secret' => $authSecret
        ]
    ]);

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at existing libraries, that is if you want to know what other devs think the proper way to implement things is.

- Guzzle (because I see that you are using it already) https://github.com/commerceguys/guzzle-oauth2-plugin
- PHPleague (acommunity with really useful examples and packages) https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client

As for setting an environment variable to capture the token/code, I think it's original. I just think (So it's my opinion) it's easier and more logical to group functionality together and remove magic whenever possible.

So I wouldn't using environment variables, because in a month or so I wouldn't easily remember where I set that variable. As you can access those environment variables everywhere in your application.

This same argument also holds true against the solution I provide though, which is to use the magic $_GET["code"] to retrieve your code.

**TLDR;** don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to, Oauth2 clients are available so use them. (most are even documented and come with their own tests \o/ so you don't have to write those)

Comment: I appreciate the comment and I did look at guzzle. However, I find the documentation and explanation to be unacceptable - something that I feel is normal for php and laravel. If I do manage to get it to work, it will act as a black box to me and I never truly know what the heck is going on.

Comment: I'll give you a good example. In the guzzle readMe, there is a config variable that calls for a username and password. Typically, in OAuth2 the user is routed to the login for the host and the client wouldn't see that name and password. So, why is this here? 

There is also no explanation of the authorization code and the process of getting the user to log into the host, getting and authorization code, getting a token, or anything else. The readMe starts of as if the user only needs a token.

Comment: Later on in the readme, they explain that you can use those object to retrieve and store tokens

Comment: As for the username and password in the config, those are your Oauth2 clients username and secretkey to connect with the provider